# jQuery Input checkboxes checked conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, calculator

Something really strange is happening to my checkboxes checked in my table.
I have built an Invoice calculator in a Table, you can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Manna/CSkLu/) and my purpose is that once i check the inputs ( Iva or Irpef) automatically they are not calculated in the Total Amount. 
As you can see in the example i have linked, if you check the *Irpef Input checkbox*, it works well, the Irpef is not calculated in the Total Amount. The problem is that it does not happen the same with my Input Checkbox IVA, why? The code is exactly the same.

When i try just to make them working separately, it's fine, both work well, so it looks like that they can not work together, it might be? What'happening? I need your help on this issue.

thanks

Here the code related to the issue:

```
function tally(selector) {
    var total = 0;
    $('p.editable_number').each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).text()) || 0;
        $('#subtotal').html(total);
        if($("#iva").is(':checked')){
            $('#subtotal').html((total).toFixed(2));
            $('#total').html((total*0.00).toFixed(2));
            $('#total1').html((total*0.15).toFixed(2));
            $('#total2').html((total*0.85).toFixed(2));
        }
        else {
            $('#subtotal').html((total).toFixed(2));
            $('#total').html((total*0.21).toFixed(2));
            $('#total1').html((total*0.15).toFixed(2));
            $('#total2').html((total*1.06).toFixed(2));
        }
         if($("#irpef").is(':checked')){
            $('#subtotal').html((total).toFixed(2));
            $('#total').html((total*0.21).toFixed(2));
            $('#total1').html((total*0.00).toFixed(2));
            $('#total2').html((total*1.21).toFixed(2));
        }
        else {
            $('#subtotal').html((total).toFixed(2))
            $('#total').html((total*0.21).toFixed(2));
            $('#total1').html((total*0.15).toFixed(2));
            $('#total2').html((total*1.06).toFixed(2));
        }
        })
        }

$('#irpef').change(function() {
             tally('p#subtotal');
             tally('p#total');
             }); 
$('#iva').change(function() {
             tally('p#subtotal');
             tally('p#total');
             });
```

Comment: Your "irpef" if/else is setting the values of the same fields as your "iva" if/else, thus overwriting the values just set. And as an aside, if you're going to use `parseInt()` on a user-entered value you _must_ supply the radix or you'll get incorrect behaviour if the user puts in leading zeros - so use `parseInt($(this).text(),10)`.

Comment: you are passing selector to tally but not using that anywhere.. ?? You if/else is being overridden...

Comment: ok, how can i avoid to override?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one, should be fine now. I think you were trying to do an else if and do everything a couple of times instead of once (each function). [refreshed](http://jsfiddle.net/CSkLu/10/)
I added variables to keep track of the total/subtotal and vat/irpf.
`each()` goes through all the p.editable_number elements, so you were executing the same code a couple of times, every time overwriting the previous results, you get the right thing because it's the end loop that counted. Now you are just getting the values once and then calculating the relevant subtotal, vat, irpf and total values(based on the condition of vat or irpf being checked or not).

Comment: Ok now it works, but it's not like i meant in the example i linked that when i check Irpef, irpef is not calculated and the Irpef amount goes to 0. Thanks

Comment: Actually the best solution would be with 0 amount for Irpef and IVA at the beginning and when i check it, they get the value percentage and the total amount is calculated including IVA and/or Irpeft.

Comment: [I see, check this out.](http://jsfiddle.net/CSkLu/14/) I think that's the effect you were going for.

Comment: Great, it was so easy as you can do it, you played again with else to set up the Value 0 to Irpef and Iva at the beginning and once clicked they get the percentage to calculate...thanks for helping

Comment: [Optimized it some more.](http://jsfiddle.net/CSkLu/22/)I don't think you need the selector parameter for the tally function, because you are not using it anywhere in this snippet of code. Glad to be of help !